# Existence of non-trivial smooth quasi-convex function on complete Riemannian manifold with finite-volume.

Tags: differential-geometry, convex-analysis, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

In this paper:
*Bishop, R.L.; O'Neill, B.*, [**Manifolds of negative curvature**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1995057), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 145, 1-49 (1969). [ZBL0191.52002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0191.52002), it has been proved that there is no non-trivial smooth convex function on complete Riemannian manifold with finite volume. My question is that is there any similar analogous for quasi-convex function?

Comment: What is a quasiconvex function?

Comment: A function $f:M\rightarrow R$ is quasiconvex if for any $x,y\in M$ and for any geodesic $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow M$ connecting $x$ and $y$,   $f(\gamma(t))\leq max(f(x),f(y)),\ \forall t\in[0,1]$.

Comment: I see. Then if you assume in addition that curvature of your manifold is negative then quasiconvex functions are again constant. In general, I am not sure.

Comment: @chandan mondal : Do you have an example s.t. non-constant function $f$ on a Riemannian manifold of an infinite volume is not convex but quasi-convex ?

Comment: @HKLee: $f(x)=x^3$, $x\in {\mathbb R}$.

Comment: @Moishe Cohen : Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Counterexample : Consider a flat manifold $M=S^1\times \mathbb{R}$.
For $(s,t)\in M$, define $f(s,t)=0$ for $t\leq 0$, $f(s,t)=t$ for
$t\in (0,1)$ and
$f(s,t)=1$ for $t\geq 1$.